# how to keep stable objects when i rotate a group object fabric.js

Tags: object, rotation, html5-canvas, fabricjs

i use fabric.js library for my html5 canvas application.

i create group of objects that i need to have stable text objects (stable position), while i rotate the group object.

1. to achieve that , i created a group object with the 2 texts and i added inside the parent group object.
2. on the '**object:rotation**'  event , i find the inside group and i keep the angle stable :

   ```
    if (obj.type == 'group'){              
          obj.angle = -actObj.angle;
          actObj.setCoords();
          canvas.renderAll();
      }
   ```

please take a look at my fiddle example :

**if i change the top position of the texts , their position is not stable when they rotate, I have to put top:-5 on the 1st text and top:5 on the 2nd text.
If i put top:-10 on the one text object and top:0 on the other , they are not stable on rotation**

```
var text = new fabric.Text(N, {
    fontSize: fontSizeTable,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    top: -5,
    fill: 'black'
});

text2 = new fabric.Text('table name rotonta', {
    fontSize: fontSizeTable,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    top: 5,
    fill: 'black'
});
```

**My jsfiddle example is here :** http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/x5q34etw/55/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the group in the center by setting top to 0:

```
var textsGroup = new fabric.Group(texts, {
         originX: 'center',
         originY: 'center',
         top:0,
         objectGroupType: 'texts'
});
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x5q34etw/63/

Comment: This one behaves strangely after resizing the shape